Singular Value Decomposition in NumPy with Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors
I have a problem with my SVD Algorithm. I am trying to teach myself the parts of Linear Algebra I missed. I am following the 'Learn' Section here Link to implement it. Attached below is my code. I am roughly sure that my eigenvector and eigenvalue solutions are correct, but somehow my calculations are missing dimensions and are off. Any help would be appreciated.
import numpy as np

def svd_2x2(A: np.ndarray) -> tuple:
  A = np.array(A)
  def get_eigenvals (A: np.ndarray):
    eigvals = []
    a , b = A[0]
    c, d = A[1]
    trace = a + d
    det = (a* d) - (b * c)
    l1 = (trace+ (trace ** 2 - (4 * det)) ** 0.5)/2
    eigvals.append(round(l1, 4))
    l2 = (trace-(trace **2 - (4 * det)) ** 0.5)/2
    eigvals.append(round(l2, 4))
    return eigvals

  def get_eigenvecs(A: np.ndarray, eigvals: np.ndarray):
    eigenvecs = []
    a,b = A[0]
    c, d = A[1]
    for eigenvalue in eigvals:
      if abs(b) > abs(c):
        v = [b, eigenvalue - a]
      else:
        v = [eigenvalue -d, c]
      mag = (v[0] **2 + v[1] ** 2) **0.5
      v = [v[0]/mag, v[1]/mag]
      eigenvecs.append(v)
    return eigenvecs
  ATA = np.matmul(A.T, A)
  AAT = np.matmul(A, A.T)

  eigvals_ATA = get_eigenvals(ATA)
  eigvals_AAT = get_eigenvals(AAT)

  V = np.array(get_eigenvecs(ATA, eigvals_ATA))
  U = np.array(get_eigenvecs(AAT, eigvals_AAT))

  S = np.diag(np.sqrt(eigvals_ATA))
  return U, S, V.T
    

I tried resizing the array, and changing both the return and ways I got Sigma (adding np.abs to offset negative values), as well as switching my helper functions out of the main method in order to try and diagnose the issues with the output. I made sure that I diagonalized the Sigma value, as looking at other posts I determined that the issue could stem from the lack of diagonalization.
